# Gesture Firefox on Mac: Swipe back tiggers Edit-->Find instead of 'Back'

Tags: macos, firefox, navigation, gesture

Whenever I use the swipe gesture to the left for browsing back like in Chrome or Safari implements it, Firefox does not browse back instead opens the search/find dialog.

The `about:config` shows which should be fine:

```
browser.gesture.swipe.left;    Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate
```

The swipe to the right for 'Forward' however works. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your answers,

Chris

Comment: That's weird... the gestures work for me. Perhaps try re-installing Firefox?

Comment: Thanks, I tried reinstalling with the same outcome :( not sure what is broken....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete deinstall with all config files did the trick.